# How to change brand when creating a stripe virtual card?

Tags: python, python-3.x, stripe-payments

Basically I am creating a card object on a cardholder and no matter where I look, I can't figure out to change the brand type from the default Visa to something like MasterCard or American Express.
Here is what I've tried but I get the error `stripe.error.InvalidRequestError: Request req_BteATbYmG7XXC2: Received unknown parameter: brand`
My code:

```
cardID = stripe.issuing.Card.create(
  cardholder=cardholderID,
  brand="MasterCard",
  type='virtual',
  currency='usd'
)
```

Comment: Believe me, I already told you, I've scrounged it I literally can't find anything. I know how to create a card but it doesn't give an example of specifying the brand. :(

Comment: Yeah, but in the create function it's giving an error that it's not a valid parameter. That's if the problem. I'm following the formats given in all the create examples

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the moment, Stripe Issuing only supports creating cards of the brand Visa. They do not support other card brands. If you use Stripe Issuing to issue cards to your customers for them to pay online or in store for example, all the cards will be issued by Visa.